# passing password to curl on command line

Tags: shell, curl, scripting

I have a requirement where I am trying to write a shell script which is calling curl command internally. I have the password, username and url stored as variables in the script. However, since I want to avoid using user:password format of curl command in the script, I am just using curl --user   command. My intention is to pass the password through stdin. So, I am trying something like this -

```
#!/bin/bash
user="abcuser"
pass="trialrun"
url="https://xyz.abc.com"
curl --user $user $url 2>&1 <<EOF
$pass
EOF
```

But this is not working. I know there are variations to this question being asked, but I didn't quite get the exact answer, hence posting this question.

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
curl -u abcuser:trialrun https://xyz.abc.comp
```

In your script:

```
curl -u ${user}:${pass} ${url}
```

To read from stdin:

```
curl  https://xyz.abc.com -K- <<< "-u user:password"
```

When using  `-K, --config` specify `-` to make curl read the file from stdin

That should work for [HTTP Basic Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), from the [curl man:](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-u)

```
-u, --user <user:password>

 Specify the user name and password to use for server authentication.
```

Comment: I do not want to use the format user:password since it can show up in clear text when we use ps command. hence passing password from stdin.

Comment: thanks! just a question here.. would the inputs provided here be visible in the history command or the ps command output?

Comment: I tested by just using `curl  https://xyz.abc.com -K-` typing later `-u user:password` and ctr-D, checked the history and just got:  `curl  https://xyz.abc.com -K-` so no passwords in the history but just check from your side, If I am right history don't save stdin

Comment: stdin won't show in history or 'ps' output - if you want to be very paranoid a herestring '<<<' will write out a temp file containing the expanded string and remove it after the curl call (you can see this in strace) - assuming your temp is unencrypted disk, then one could dream up a paranoid/difficult scenario where this could be recovered. I believe if you pipe from a built-in printf, it won't ever touch the disk, nor will it be visible in history or ps.

Comment: Note for automation users: in case your passwords can contain special characters such solutions can easily break. Consider to use base64 to encode passwords, and decode them on the fly.

Comment: Additional Note for automation users:  BASE64 would not shield the secret from 'ps' or shell history, if you are using scripts relying on external commands (like `base64`). Do this in code (if you must use Bash for this, use builtins to implement base64, not external commands).

Answer (score 6):

To expand on @nbari's answer, if you have a tool "get-password" that can produce a password on stdout, you can safely use this invocation:

```
user="abcuser"
url="https://xyz.abc.com"
get-password $user | sed -e "s/^/-u $user:/" | curl -K- $url
```

The password will be written to a pipe. We use `sed` to massage the password into the expected format. The password will therefore never be visible in `ps` or in the history.

Comment: Without sed: `echo "-u $user:$(get-password $user)" | curl -K- $url`